# User authentication support for Rails, NOT authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

Which authentication plugin for Rails would you choose? I'm not interested in the permissions, roles and other authorization stuff.

I'm interested in the:

- user model/controllers generation
- predefined components to support various ways of authentication (HTML form, OpenID) with various back-end (database, LDAP, textfile).

I'm looking for something similar to the Java Spring Security (formerly Acegi) but for Rails platform.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic).  It's incredibly flexible and simple to get started.

Other options:

[Clearance](http://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance)

[Devise](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise) (Rack-based)

Answer (score 1):

Ruby Toolbox provides a nice list of [Rails Authentication plugins](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authentication.html).

I used `restful_authentication` in the past but I switched to `authlogic` 1 year ago.
Authlogic is an excellent and high customizable plugin, there are also additional third party plugins to support OpenID and Facebook logins.

I heard good words about [Clearance](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/159805955/clearance-rails-authentication-for-developers-who) but I never used it.